# Javascript button tooltip (bootgrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery-bootgrid

How can I add tooltip or mouseover in button

```
            {
               return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button>";
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Note: I created the button inside javascript (bootgrid) not html.